# Is there a way to continue query in a different variable? and then combine both query?

Tags: php, postgresql

prepare($sql);
$query->execute();

$q1 = .$sql."WHERE t.qcode = 1";

?>

Comment: Your question could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as code, citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your question is correct and are able to answer. You can find more information on how to write good questions in the help center.

Answer (score 0):

you must first prepare the query.
I'd do this...

```
$q1 = $sql."WHERE t.qcode = 1";
if($condition){
    $q1 .= " and name ='john doe' ";
}
prepare($q1); 
$query->execute();
```

Pd: don't forget the space in the begin of string concatened